# Failed to call uniswap swapExactTokensForTokens in a contract

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, ethers.js

```
contract TestCall {
    ...

    function call(address payable _to, uint256 _value, bytes calldata _data) external onlyOwner payable returns (bytes memory) {
        require(_to != address(0));
        (bool _success, bytes memory _result) = _to.call{value: _value}(_data);
        require(_success);
        return _result;
    }

    ...
}
```

I deployed the above contract in the goerli testnet.
And use the following js code to swap token2 to token1 by calling the `TestCall.call` function.

```
import { BigNumber, Contract, providers, Wallet, utils } from "ethers";
const provider = new providers.StaticJsonRpcProvider(ETHEREUM_RPC_URL);
const wallet = new Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY, provider); // The account which deployed the contract
const signingAddr = await wallet.getAddress();
const uniswapInterface = new Contract(UNISWAP_ROUTERV2_ADDRESS, UNISWAP_ROUTERV2_ABI, wallet);
const testCallContract = new Contract(TESTCALL_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, TESTCALL_ABI, wallet);
const nonce = await wallet.getTransactionCount();
const gasPriceGwei = "100"; // in GWEI
const gasPriceWei = utils.parseUnits(gasPriceGwei, "gwei");

const amountIn = BigNumber.from(1000000000000);
let amountOut = await uniswapInterface.getAmountsOut(amountIn, [token2Addr, token1Addr]);
amountOut = amountOut[1];
const amountOutMin = amountOut.mul(0.998 * 1000).div(1000);
const params = {
  "amountIn": amountIn,
  "amountOutMin": amountOutMin,
  "path": [token2Addr, token1Addr],
  "to": signingAddr,
  "deadline": Date.now() + 1000*60*10,
};
console.log("params", params)

/// This can run successfully.
// const tx = await uniswapInterface.swapExactTokensForTokens(...Object.values(params), {
//   "value": BigNumber.from(0),
//   "gasLimit": utils.hexlify(1000000),
//   "gasPrice": gasPriceWei,
//   "nonce": nonce
// });
// const receipt = await tx.wait()
// console.log(receipt)

const tx = await uniswapInterface.populateTransaction.swapExactTokensForTokens(...Object.values(params));
console.log(tx);
if (tx === undefined || tx.data === undefined) throw new Error("ERROR")

const transaction = await testCallContract.call(UNISWAP_ROUTERV2_ADDRESS, BigNumber.from(0), tx.data, {
  "value": BigNumber.from(0),
  "gasLimit": utils.hexlify(1000000),
  "gasPrice": gasPriceWei,
  "nonce": nonce,
});
console.log("transaction", JSON.stringify(transaction))
const receipt = await transaction.wait()
console.log(receipt)
```

Can't find useful info in the error message:

```
Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]
```

It runs successfully with `swapExactETHForTokens`:

```
const amountInEther = '0.01';
const amountIn = utils.parseEther(amountInEther);
let amountOut = await uniswapInterface.getAmountsOut(amountIn, [WETH_ADDRESS, token2Addr]);
console.log(amountOut);
amountOut = amountOut[1];
const amountOutMin = amountOut.mul(0.998 * 1000).div(1000);
const params = {
  "amountOutMin": amountOutMin,
  "path": [WETH_ADDRESS, token2Addr],
  "to": signingAddr,
  "deadline": Date.now() + 1000*60*10,
};
const tx1 = await uniswapInterface.populateTransaction.swapExactETHForTokens(...Object.values(params), {"value": amountIn});
console.log(tx1);
if (tx1 === undefined || tx1.data === undefined) throw new Error("ERROR");

const transaction = await bundleExecutorContract.call(UNISWAP_ROUTERV2_ADDRESS, BigNumber.from(amountIn), tx1.data, {
  "value": amountIn,
  "gasLimit": utils.hexlify(1000000),
  "gasPrice": gasPriceWei,
  "nonce": nonce,
});
console.log("transaction", JSON.stringify(transaction))
const receipt = await transaction.wait()
console.log(receipt)
```

Is there someway to debug solidity code deployed in a testnet?
I searched and find hardhat, but don't know how to use it in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix:

- In the contract code, approve enough token2 for UNISWAP_ROUTERV2_ADDRESS. And send enough token2 to
  TESTCALL_CONTRACT_ADDRESS.
- As swapExactTokensForTokens is not payable, in the js code, set value to 0.

  `"value": BigNumber.from(0),`